# sorting an array according to the order of another array - pair inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, go

so I have two arrays - arrOne = [10, 2, 3, 14, 1] and arrTwo = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4];

I want sort the arrTwo and use the same indexing changes on arrOne, ie arrTwo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], arrOne [10, 2, 3, 1, 14].

I've been trying to implement it with merge sort, but it does not work. The recursion obstructs me from doing what I intended.

Important to note, I am getting the data as two integers at a time and push them into separate arrays, using the previous arrays that would mean -

1. input 10 ,1
2. input 2, 2
3. input 3, 3
4. input 14, 5
5. input 1, 4

Perhaps a different data structure could be used, but I am not aware of it.

I have put go as a tag since I would like to solve it both languages.

Answer (score 1):

Create a 2d array which holds value of 2 arrays and extract 2 arrays after sorting.

```js
let arrOne = [10, 2, 3, 14, 1],
  arrTwo = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4];



arrOne
  // create 2d array which contains both array values
  .map((v, i) => [v, arrTwo[i]])
  // sort the combined array based on first array element
  .sort(([a], [b]) => a - b)
  // update the main arrays
  .forEach(([v1, v2], i) => {
    arrOne[i] = v1;
    arrTwo[i] = v2;
  })

console.log(arrOne, arrTwo)
```

Comment: Nice answer to the sorting of two arrays  my answer is based on the usage of two arrays not really being the right data structure for this.

Comment: awesome stuff, just have to figure out how to get this done in Go. thanks Pranav!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I would not use two arrays.

I would push an object to a single array. Making it much more structured keeping the data “together”

```
const data = [{
 one: 10,
 two: 1
},
{
 one: 2,
 two: 2
},

{
 one: 3,
  two: 3
},

{
 one: 14,
 two: 5
},
{
 one: 1,
 two: 4
}
```

To add another input:

```
data.push({
   one: 200,
   two: 6
})
```

Then sort by key “two”

```
data.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.two-b.two
})
```

Just note that the sort will mutate the array but you can copy if this is an issue. Guessing sorting the original array is not a problem for your use case anyway.